# React render run before fetch method receives token from server

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, oauth, token, fetch

I have a JS file within my React application, which connects to the server, sends username and password, receives an oauth token from the server and stores the token in the local storage.
 However before the token received by react, the react sends the next request before token stored in the local storage. Which leads to 401 unauthorized access.

**AuthService.js**

```
 login(username, password) {
    console.log(username);
     return this.fetch(`${this.domain}/api/AuthAPI/getCredentials`, {
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*"    
        }
    }).then(res => {
        this.fetch(`${this.domain}/Token`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: 'grant_type=password&username=' + res[0]
        }).then(response => {
            var date_token_issue = new Date();
            this.setToken(response.access_token,response.expires_in, date_token_issue) // Setting the token in localStorage
            return Promise.resolve(response);
        })
    })

}

setToken(idToken,expires, date_token_issue ) {
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', idToken)
    localStorage.setItem('expires', expires)
    localStorage.setItem('date_token_issue', date_token_issue)
}
```

**SignIn.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import AuthService from '../comonents/AuthService';
import Orders from '../../app/orders/orders'
import { Redirect, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
export default function SignIn(AuthComponent){
const Auth = new AuthService('http://localhost:53050');

return class AuthWrapped extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        user: null,
        loggedIn: false
    }
}

async componentDidMount() {
  if (!Auth.loggedIn()) {
    const promise = await  Auth.login('m.dawaina', 'm.dawaina');
    console.log(promise)
    this.setState({loggedIn: true});
  }
  else {
      try {            
        this.setState({loggedIn: true})
          const profile = Auth.getProfile()
          this.setState({
              user: profile
          })               
      }
      catch(err){
          Auth.logout()
          //this.props.history.replace('/login')
      }
  }
 }

render() {
if (this.state.loggedIn) {      

    return (
      <div>  
        <Redirect to='/orders'/>       
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/orders" component={Orders} />         
        </Switch>
      </div>
    )
}
else {
  return (       
          <AuthComponent history={this.props.history} user={this.state.user} />
         )
     }
   }

 }
}
```

I need a way to force react wait for the JS receives the token and stores it in the local storage, and prevent react sending the next request until it finds the token stored in the local storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
login(username, password) {
console.log(username);
 return this.fetch(`${this.domain}/api/AuthAPI/getCredentials`, {
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*"    
    }
}).then(res => {
    // Add a return here
    return this.fetch(`${this.domain}/Token`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: 'grant_type=password&username=' + res[0]
    }).then(response => {
        var date_token_issue = new Date();
        this.setToken(response.access_token,response.expires_in, date_token_issue) // Setting the token in localStorage
        return Promise.resolve(response);
    })
})
```

You need to add a return to the then function so that await will wait for the inner promise to resolve.

Comment: Thanks Sibin for your valuable answer. The console.log(promise) now returns the token. However the request still sent without token. although when I refresh the page the request sent with token

Comment: ConfigureStore runs before token stored in the localstorage, how can I prevent this

Comment: Are you using redux? How are you calling the ConfigureStore?

Comment: const client = axios.create({   
    responseType: 'json'
  });
  client.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + Auth.getToken();
console.log('ttt '+ Auth.getToken());
export const configureStore = preloadedState => {
   
const store = createStore(
    reducers, //custom reducers
    preloadedState,
     composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk,
      axiosMiddleware(axios.create(axiosMiddleware(client))), //second parameter options can optionally contain onSuccess, onError, onComplete, successSuffix, errorSuffix
    ))
  )
  return store;
};

Comment: I call configure store from the index.js like this

Comment: const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter > 
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
     document.getElementById('root')
);

Comment: Set the header like this.
if (!Auth.loggedIn()) {
    const token = await  Auth.login('m.dawaina', 'm.dawaina');
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
    this.setState({loggedIn: true});
  }

Comment: I tried your suggestion and its working now. Thanks Sibin for your support. Appreciate it :)